# Using Reap Sow to define unsorted union

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, sow-reap

In the documentation of `Reap` under "Applications" paragraph there is this example:

```
Reap[Sow[1, {b, b, c, a, c, a, b, d}], _, # &]

(* {1, {b, c, a, d}} *)
```

The second part of the output represents unsorted union of `{b, b, c, a, c, a, b, d}`.

I do not understand how this works. Neither `Reap` nor `Sow` represent any cycle or condition if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Ahhh... there is the cycle... I did not know that `Sow[1, {b, b, c, a, c, a, b, d}]` works like mapping over the second argument. Anyway, I have never used `Reap - Sow` in any code and I don't think I ever will.

Comment: `Reap`/`Sow` can be useful to monitor steps or evaluations when numerically solving a problem with functions like `NDSolve`, `FindRoot` etc. For example [EvaluationMonitor](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html)

Comment: In addition, to list duplicates (using Reap/Sow): `Reap[Sow[1,{b, b, c, a, c, a, b, d}],_,Pick[#1,Unitize[Length@#2-1],1]&][[2]]`  or to delete ALL duplicates (using Reap/Sow): `Reap[Sow[1,{b, b, c, a, c, a, b, d}],_,Pick[#1,#2,{1}]&][[2]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that

```
Sow[1, {b, b, c, a, c, a, b, d}]
```

is equivalent to

```
Sow[1,b]; Sow[1,b]; Sow[1,c]; Sow[1,a]; Sow[1,c]; Sow[1,a]; Sow[1,b]; Sow[1,d]
```

in the sense that they sow the same thing: They sow (the value 1) 3 times with tag b, 2 times with tag c, 2 times with tag a, 1 time with tag d. See the [3rd syntax of Sow in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html).

Therefore

```
Reap[Sow[1,{b,b,c,a,c,a,b,d}],_,f]
(* {1,{f[b,{1,1,1}],f[c,{1,1}],f[a,{1,1}],f[d,{1}]}} *)
```

consistent with the [4th syntax of Reap in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

In the example that OP considers, `f = # &`, which is the same as `f = #1 &`. For example, `f[b,{1,1,1}]` evaluates to `b`. This explains why

```
Reap[Sow[1,{b,b,c,a,c,a,b,d}],_,#&]
(* {1,{b,c,a,d}} *)
```